# Edwards/zeta function: first proof of the functional equation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

In Edwards "Riemann's zeta function", regarding the proof of the zeta functional equation p.14, it is stated without proof that $1/(e^z-1)$ is bounded (I have to assume independently of $n$) on the circle $C(0,(2n+1)\pi$). If the result is quite straightforward when considering the square $\pm n\pm i(2n+1)\pi$ instead, I struggle to prove this fact for the circle. Since the function is not holomorphic, I cannot use the maximum principle and view the circle as part of the square.

The result is clear at the following four points of the circle:

At $z=\pm i(2n+1)\pi, 1/(e^z-1)=-1/2$.

At $z=(2n+1)\pi,  1/(e^z-1)=1/(e^{(2n+1)\pi}-1)\le 1$.

At $z=-(2n+1)\pi,  1/(e^z-1)=1/(e^{-(2n+1)\pi}-1)$ of modulus $\le 2$ for $n$ large.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: because the singularities are on the main axis of the circle you can just deform it into a rightangle

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I don't understand it though. Could you please give more details?

Comment: But why is the bound independent of $n$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A brute force answer:

Observe that
$$|e^z - 1| = (e^{\operatorname{Re} z} - 1)^2 + 2e^{\operatorname{Re} z}(1 - \cos(\operatorname{Im}z)).$$

Divide the circle into two parts:  $|\operatorname{Re} z| \geq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\pi$ and $|\operatorname{Re} z| \leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\pi$.

If $|\operatorname{Re} z| \geq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\pi$, then
$$|e^z - 1| \geq (\operatorname{Re} z)^2 \geq \frac{3}{4} \pi^2.$$

If $|\operatorname{Re} z| \leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\pi$, then
$$\sqrt{((2n+1)\pi)^2 - 3\pi^2/4} \leq |\operatorname{Im} z| \leq (2n+1)\pi,$$
which we can also write as
$$\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \sqrt{((2n+1)\pi)^2 - 3\pi^2/4} - 2n\pi \leq |\operatorname{Im} z| - 2n\pi \leq \pi.$$
Therefore
$$\cos(\operatorname{Im} z) \leq 0$$
and so
$$|e^z - 1| \geq 2e^{-\sqrt{3}\pi / 2}.$$

Comment: Thanks very much John ! Very nice actually. I think that you should split the case $|Rez|\ge \sqrt{3}\pi/2$ into two subcases as the case $Rez\le - \sqrt{3}\pi/2$ is quite different and would lead to $|e^z-1|^2\ge (1-e^{\sqrt{3}\pi/2})^2$.